# Using Rewrite in .htaccess instead of Alias in httpd.conf

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, alias, firefox4

Trying to setup up my own Weave server on shared host, obviously I cannot modify httpd.conf file so I try to find a work-around using Rewrite module and .htaccess.

Based on documentation here https://wiki.mozilla.org/Labs/Weave/Sync/1.1/Setup and https://wiki.mozilla.org/Labs/Weave/User/1.0/Setup I created *.htaccess*

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^1.1(.*) server-sync/1.1/index.php/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^1.0(.*) server-sync/1.0/index.php/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^user/1.0(.*) weaveserver-registration/1.0/index.php/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^user/1(.*) weaveserver-registration/1.0/index.php/$1 [L]
```

instead of

```
Alias /1.0 <full path to weave directory>/server-sync/1.1/index.php
Alias /1.1 <full path to weave directory>/server-sync/1.1/index.php
Alias /user/1.0 <full path to weave directory>/weaveserver-registration/1.0/index.php
Alias /user/1 <full path to weave directory>/weaveserver-registration/1.0/index.php
```

but I could not get it worked. I always get *Please enter a valid server URL* when I setup "**http://www.mydomain.com/dir/weave**" as Sync URL in Firefox 4.

are these Rewrite rules correct? if so I can prob weave-server config settings :/
Directory structure of my hosted scripts:

```
/home/myname/www/dir/weave/.htaccess
/home/myname/www/dir/weave/server-sync > weave server scripts
/home/myname/www/dir/weave/weaveserver-registration > weave server user scripts
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not know how weave requests file, but I think you can test this:

```
RewriteRule ^1.1(.*) dir/weave/server-sync/1.1/index.php$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^1.0(.*) dir/weaveserver-sync/1.0/index.php$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^user/1.0(.*) dir/weaveweaveserver-registration/1.0/index.php$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^user/1(.*) dir/weaveweaveserver-registration/1.0/index.php$1 [L]
```

Your base directory being `/ = /home/myname/www/` your rules should rewrite request to `/1.0` to `dir/weave/server-sync/1.0/index.php$1` where `$1` is anything that stands after `/1.0` request. (Note the removed slash ! Or you may end with doubled slashes).

Comment: yeah I dont know Weave file requests structure as well and I have already used that in my first code. I again get the same error. so I think my rewrite code should be fine?