# Is it possible to rewrite an alias of httpd.conf to htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, httpd.conf

Trying to rewrite an alias in **.htaccess**. The problem is that the alias is already defined in the **httpd.conf** of the server.

So, is it possible to "override" that rule in **.htaccess** for the redirect is effective only for the site in question?

Knowing that I have no access to **httpd.conf**.

Comment: Please follow this link, that may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5647697/using-rewrite-in-htaccess-instead-of-alias-in-httpd-conf

Comment: I don’t think that’s possible – RewriteRules on different “levels” don’t overwrite each other, they are only applied successively. Although if the rewrite from httpd.conf “lands” within the reach of your .htaccess rewrite, then you could rewrite it _again_ there.

Comment: Yes i saw it @Zeshan, It is not stated how we can rewrite a rule of **httpd.conf** in the **.htaccess**. 
Indeed, this is what I want to do.

Comment: The alias directive is a way to map an url to a directory which is not under the DocumentRoot. So, when the browser read the htaccess it is because it has allready "read" the url and decided which directory to serve. From you question I don't understand what you want to do: do you want to redirect the user to another url/directory? Or you want you want to serve the same directory under different aliases?

Comment: Ok, so is it impossible? I think i can do this with a PHP script.

Comment: Even in PHP it is impossible to rewrite an alias for the **httpd.conf**. With header location or other redirection. Is there any solution?

Comment: I Wanted to redirect the user to another url/directory with overwrite the alias. But according to my research it's not possible. I had to remove the alias.